# Trying to get large sitelinks, I have small sitelinks

Tags: seo, sitelinks, technical-seo

I'm at my wits end and I have no idea what I can do to my site to get sitelinks.

I've done everything the SEO "experts" say you should do:

- Site is indexed and has over 300 clicks per day, about 10,000 impressions per month
- Site has clear structure implemented with breadcrumbs
- Site has a consistent header menu with clear menu item tagging that matches the breadcrumb order in schema

I've had multiple developers look at my site and they are perplexed as to why I'm not getting site links.

My company has built and published totally new sites for clients, and they get sitelinks almost instantly after getting indexed, and that's without any of the points listed above.

What else do I need to do? What's the secret to getting large sitelinks? We currently have small sitelinks, but it looks unprofessional and like we don't have control over our own brand. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Is small vs large a quantity problem or a size problem?

Comment: Sitelinks are managed by the search engine's company (SEC, I'm assuming you're targeting Google). It's managed based on a few rules that nobody except the SEC knows exactly but a few of them are well known. One of them is making sure the brand's name and domain name are unique enough. If that failed, it's an uphill battle. Did you make sure of this?

Comment: @Mast Small sitelinks appear at the bottom of the search results. I want professional looking sitelinks that appear in large text format. The brand is unique enough to come up at the top of google when googled directly. Like I said, hundreds of clicks per day and 10000+ impressions per month, including for my own brand. That's why I'm so confused when we build a site that has no search presence, domain authority, or clear breadcrumb structure, but it gets sitelinks as soon as it gets indexed. It's totally counterintuitive.